# Will my teams bot application work if my application in Azure active directory and Azure bot are in two different accounts?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service, teams-toolkit

So I have a scenario where my sso app registration is in Azure active directory at dev1@mycompanyonline.com and my bot is provisioned using Azure bot in Azure portal that's in dev2@mycompanyonline.com. my bot web service is hosted publicly on Https with URL .../api/messages endpoint configured in Azure bot.

What can I do to make this work ? Currently when I upload my app package to teams it doesn't work and says something went wrong with no error. What could be the issue?

I provisioned cloud resources using teams tool kit and deployed my services again using teams toolkit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the `Azure Bot` resource, you also create an Azure App Registration. This resource is also where you configure SSO authentication. The Azure `App Service` (or alternative server solution) actually hosts and runs the Bot as a web app. If you are trying to put the `Azure Bot` in the `dev1` tenant and the `App Service` in the `dev2` tenant, then this scenario should work as long as the bot's `AppType` is `MultiTenant`.

I haven't always had the best luck publishing a bot with Teams Toolkit. You might try the method in the [docs on publishing a bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/provision-and-publish-a-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=userassigned%2Ccsharp).